# Prompt a user for filename and path, test if file exists, if it doesn't exist create a blank file with that name

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, input, prompt

So far I have this

```
#!/bin/bash 
printf -x "What file are you looking for?: " read x
if [ -x x.txt ]
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "nok"
fi
```

But I have no idea where to go next, I need to have the user input a file, I need it to check if that file exists wich I think I have and after that check I need it to either verify that it's there or I need it to create a blank file with that name. I am really new to Shell Scripting and Bash scripting in general so I am sorry if this is super basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invert the if operation, by checking if a file under user input doesn't exist. You can use `!` "not" logical operation to negate it.

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "What file are you looking for ?\n"
read file

if [ ! -f $file ]; then
  printf "%s doesn't exist, creating the file..\n" "$file"
  touch $file
else
  printf "%s already exist !\n" "$file"
fi
```

The result.

```
$ ls
file1  test.sh
$ ./test.sh 
What file are you looking for ?
file1
file1 already exist !
$ ./test.sh 
What file are you looking for ?
file2
file2 doesn't exist, creating the file..
$ ls
file1  file2  test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you sm for your response, I copied everything to the T and my ls shows ``` $file  test ```

Comment: Yea I've been trying to fix it to bring the file name instead of $file, I think it has something to do with ```touch $file```

Comment: @Yorgito Create new file called `test.sh`, copy the content of above script, grant execute privilege to the file, then run it.

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry I'm a little slow with this